# How to read Toast notification aloud?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android text to speech message application.When the message received as a **Toast** notification, I want to read it aloud.So how can I read the message inside the **Toast** notification as a voice.

There are 3 classes in my project
1) for sending message
2)receiving message
3)public class Text2Speech extends Activity implements OnInitListener(to convert to voice)

I want to pass the Toast class notification into **Text2Speech** class from receiving class inorder to convert it into voice.Please tell me how can I do this,, and how can I invoke my
Text2Speech class when I received a message notification.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

This Documentation explains the text to speech including examples...

Comment: Tnzz.. :) bt my problem is still there. I want to know is there any way to read the content of the notification aloud. As an example, when a text message received,instead of normal message alert tone,It should read the content of the notification to the receiver.. :)